# SSRS - creating chart - overlapping year - end of year/start of next

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have to report on some data covering November, December of 2013 and Jan, Feb of 2014. I know how to chart over a calendar year but I'm struggling with this...any one know how i can chart this in nov,dec,jan,feb order???

cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have to have some field available in your dataset or a calculation based upon a field/fields that orders them correctly. If you have something like yyyy-mm (ex: 2013-11) you can set the sort order of the category group within your chart. Leave the actual value as you want it to be seen, just change the sort order.

Here's a good blog post that (I think) explains exactly what you are trying to do:  http://www.allaboutmssql.com/2013/06/ssrs-in-charts-how-to-sort-labels-on-x.html

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data first by `=Year(Fields!YourDateField.Value)` and then by `=Month(Fields!YourDateField.Value)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input... i found this [Custom ordering of series field for stacked chart in SSRS08 TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816032/custom-ordering-of-series-field-for-stacked-chart-in-ssrs08-tfs)

so i manually changed the value value with a switch and then ordered A-Z

All good now

cheers